# Android: how to stop listener when app closes

Tags: java, android

When my app starts I start a location listener, I'd like to turn it off when the user exits the app, whether by pressing the back button or just putting it in the background, and I would like to resume listening when the app is back.

I couldn't find `onPause/onResume` for the app level, so I thought about holding a counter that will count the number of active activities and if it's 0 it will shut down the listener, but there must be a better way...

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect if your app is running in background you can read this article:

http://www.vardhan-ds.co.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html

And to shut down your listener, you just need to remove the Listener from your manager.
If you need some help with this I can post some code, but I think this description will help you.

Comment: Thanks, i used the code in the post and it seems to be working.